# How do I disable the "Review step" page?

Tags: 7, commerce

I do not want to show the *Review step* page which comes after the *Cart* page. Is there any way to disable/skip that page?

Comment: You can try disabling the "review" pane in this page admin/commerce/config/checkout and then override the buttons' text to replace "review order" with "enter payment details" for example

Answer (score 1):

Just remove any checkout panes from it in the checkout form configuration.